# Understanding type destructuring in Elm

Tags: elm

I am trying to understand all the different ways in which types can be defined and pattern matched in Elm.

While searching for code to learn from, I found an implementation in pure Elm of a JSON decoder. The code can be found [here](https://ellie-app.com/vLfXvswyj5a1) and the article series [here](https://8thlight.com/blog/kofi-gumbs/2017/06/28/elm-json-decoding-types.html).

I cannot understand the *style* used in the **field** function:

```
type Value
    = Jnull
    | Jobject (Dict String Value)

type Decoder a
    = Decoder (Value -> Result String a)

decodeValue : Decoder a -> Value -> Result String a
decodeValue (Decoder attemptToDecode) value =
    attemptToDecode value

field : String -> Decoder a -> Decoder a
field key (Decoder parameterAttempt) =
    let
        decodeKey object =
            Dict.get key object
                |> Result.fromMaybe "couldn't find key"
                |> Result.andThen parameterAttempt

        attemptToDecode value =
            case value of
                Jobject foundIt ->
                    decodeKey foundIt

                _ ->
                    Err "not an object"
    in
        Decoder attemptToDecode
```

The test written for the function looks like this:

```
test "decodes a field" <|
            \_ ->
                Jobject (Dict.singleton "nested" (Jnumber 5.0))
                    |> decodeValue (field "nested" int)
                    |> Expect.equal (Ok 5)
```

I don't understand the body of the let. Why is there an assignment like this and how does the code get evaluated? How is

> Dict.get key object

handled and "bound" to?

> decodeKey object = ...
>
> attemptToDecode value = ...

Fundamentally I am trying to understand what happens in the let such that it returns something "useful" for **Decoder attemptToDecode**. Also, is there a better way of expressing what is intended?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems to me you are looking at an example more complicated than your understanding allows, then asking a question that doesn't make sense here, and likely won't be helpful to others. For that reason I'll have to vote to close. `decodeKey object` is defining a function called `decodeKey` with parameter `object` implemented by the code that follows. `|>` is a pipeline operator covered in the intro docs. The result of `Dict.get key object` is piped to the code that follows. ALL of that is the implementation of `decodeKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @zh5 makes a valid point in the sense that:

1. this is probably either not the right example for you to learn from at this point (for whatever you are trying to accomplish)
2. or if it is, you should be able to understand it without asking this question.

On the other hand, trying to understand something just out of curiosity is a good thing even if it is not always particularly useful, so I will make an attempt to help.

---

This is the intent of `field` (I assume):

> Give me *"the logic"* in a `Decoder` that I can use to decode a field
>   and give me a field name. I will take *"the logic"* out of your `Decoder`,
>   put some *"extra logic"* on top of it to find
>   the field in a JSON object, and I will give you back this combined
>   logic in a new `Decoder`.

So, that "extra logic" is split into two parts in the code above:

1. `attemptToDecode` captures the logic for ensuring that whatever is being decoded is a JSON object. The value of this JSON object is represented as a dictionary which is extracted and passed on to the second part. 
   (If whatever is being decoded is not an object the result should be an error, obviously.)
2. `decodeKey` captures the other half of the logic. Having the content of the JSON object in the form of a dictionary, now we should find the field and try to decode it using *"the logic"* that was supplied in the `Decoder`. This logic is deconstructed from the decoder and called `parameterAttempt` in the code. 
   (Obviously, if the field cannot be found in the JSON object the result should be an error.)

Now, `attemptToDecode` refers to `decodeKey` which then refers to `parameterAttempt` (the original logic passed for decoding the field), so we can say that `attemptToDecode` *captures the whole logic that is needed to decode a field from a JSON object*. So at this point, all that needs to be done is to wrap this logic back into a `Decoder`, which is exactly what the code says:

`Decoder attemptToDecode`

And, surely you are right in your own answer that the logic captured in the decoders is captured in the form of functions, and when these functions refer to each other their type signatures must match up at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The Decoder type defined as:

```
type Decoder a
    = Decoder (Value -> Result String a)
```

has one data constructor taking one argument. This means that in order to build a Decoder we need a function which takes a Value and returns a Result String a:

```
f: Value -> Result String a -> Decoder a
```

The assignments inside the **let** are building functions and are used as building blocks. Reading them with their type definitions makes things clearer.

```
let
    decodeKey: Dict String Value -> Result String a
    decodeKey object =
        case Dict.get key object of
            Just value ->
                parameterAttempt value

            Nothing ->
                Err "couldn't find key"

    attemptToDecode: Value -> Result String a
    attemptToDecode value =
        case value of
            Jobject foundIt ->
                decodeKey foundIt

            _ ->
                Err "not an object"
in
    Decoder attemptToDecode
```

**attemptToDecode** uses the **decodeKey** and can do so because both return

> Result String a

Any feedback on this is very much appreciated.